# Table row expands outside of view because images won't scale

Tags: android, scaling, tablelayout, image-scaling

I've a layout that contains amongst other the following table:

```
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1a"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:background="#338877"  >

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewSugarLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/label_sugar"
            android:textColor="#00a7ce"
            android:textColorLink="#00a7ce"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_sugar_0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="TEST" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_sugar_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/button_sugar_off"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_sugar_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/button_sugar_off" 
            android:scaleType="centerInside" 
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_sugar_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/button_sugar_off"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"  />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_sugar_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/button_sugar_off"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"  />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_sugar_5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/button_sugar_off"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"  />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_sugar_6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/button_sugar_off"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"  />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

What I got is, the table row expands outside the right border of the view (because the button-images are not scaled and thus to big). What I need would be a scaling of the images to allow for that. What I don't have is an idea, why it doesn't do that 8)

Any pointers appreciated!

Best regards,
Marcus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution: Add

android:stretchColumns="true"
  android:shrinkColumns="true"

to your

```
<TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, just setting your ImageButton width and height to `wrap_content` would not work as it will only make your View as big as its source (original) size. Have you considered layouting with a different viewgroup, such as LinearLayout or RelativeLayout?

Comment: I had it as vertical liners in the first try, but as I have several rows, that had the effect, that all items were distributed evenly horizontally, but each vertical layout had a different height. so, given a table with images, what's the layout to choose if i want even distribution and scaling to parent_width?